# Looping the information in the two-level link

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

If my link have one level: localhost:3000/item
I see (and so should be): 
[image]

but if two level link: localhost:3000/item/1

[image]

Changed route in app.js:

```
$routeProvider
        .when('/item', {templateUrl: '/partials/menu/item', controller: 'ItemCtrl'});
```

And jade:

```
    .deckgrid(deckgrid,source="photos",cardTemplate="app/deckgrid/deckgrid-template.html")
```

Comment: can't able to understand your question can u make it bit clear?

Comment: I need two level link, but I can not use it because looping  information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the app can't find a file (i.e., otherwise), then it will redirect to the root, which in this case loads the templateUrl. But if your templateUrl is wrong, then it will cause a recursion that reloads index.html loading angular (and everything else) over and over.
Path was a mistake("/"):

```
.deckgrid(deckgrid,source="photos",cardTemplate="/app/deckgrid/deckgrid-template.html")
```